# Evaluating a double integral using normal density

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

$(1)$ Compute the value of $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)} dx dy $$

***What I tried*** :$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)} dx dy $$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{y} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx) dy $$

Now, let $$t=\frac{x^2}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow dt= x dx$$
$$\Rightarrow dx= x^{-1} dt$$
$$\Rightarrow dx= (2t)^{\frac{-1}{2}} dt$$
Again, $$x\in (-\infty,y)$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2\in (0,\infty)$$
So, 
 $$I=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{y} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx) dy $$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}(2t)^{\frac{-1}{2}}dt) dy $$
$$=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}(t)^{\frac{-1}{2}}dt) dy $$
$$=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}(\Gamma{\frac{1}{2}}) dy $$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy $$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy) $$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \times 1 $$
(The integrand being a standard normal  density)

$$I=\frac{1}{2}$$

Am I correct ?

Comment: It you read the original integral as $\mathbb P(X \le Y)$ with $X,Y$ i.i.d standard normal then yes this is $\frac12$ (as indeed it would be for i.i.d. any continuous distribution)

Comment: The step "$x\in (-\infty,y)\Rightarrow x^2\in (0,\infty)$" is frankly wrong and leads you to compute $P(Y\in\mathbb R,X>0)$ instead of $P(X<Y)$.

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. Actually I used intuition that if $X$ takes  infinitely large negative values then its square will take infinitely large positive values. Ultimately, square of any real quantity lies in the interval $(0,\infty)$ or $x^2\le0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick way.

Observe that $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y}$ defines exactly half of the $(x,y)$-plane. Since the integrand depends on $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ only, the result is $1/2$ of the integral over the full $(x,y)$-plane, and this can be favorably computed in spherical coordinates:

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)} dx dy = \\
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2} r^2} r dr \int_{0}^{2 \pi}d\phi = \\
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2} r^2}  d(\frac{r^2}{2}) = -e^{-\frac{1}{2} r^2} |_0^{\infty} = 1
$$
So, yes, your integral equals $1/2$.