# An Integration problem of Bivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: integration

I'm currently solving previous years problems for my M.Sc Statistics entrance exam on IIT (India).

**Problem->**

Find the value of

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^y e^{\frac{-1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)}\mathop{dx} \mathop{dy}$$

This is a PDF of Bivariate Normal(0,0,1,1,cor=0)
Now I can't find an right approach to solve it, I tried integrating but it became messed up as after using the integration by parts form. Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: If you can use that this is circularly symmetric and a distribution, then you may exploit the symmetry, right? A distribution adds up to 1, it is divided into two symmetrical parts, each part shall add up to 0.5? If you wish to deal with the double integral typical approach would be making the exponent square.

Comment: This has been asked before but I cannot find the question.

Comment: Here's one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675055/evaluating-a-double-integral-using-normal-density.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integral is $\int_{(x,\,y)\in\Bbb R^2\land x\le y}\phi(x)\phi(y)dxdy$, with $\phi$ the $N(0,\,1)$ pdf. Therefore, it is the probability $x\le y$ subject to $x,\,y$ being $N(0,\,1)$ iids. In other words, $1/2$.